# VirtuaWin shows Visual Studio 2010 in all Desktops

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop, virtuawin

I'm using VirtuaWin in Windows 7 to have virtual desktop functionality and I think this program is awesome.

There's one small issue, though: on the computer at work, when moving to another desktop it hides all windows in the current desktop, except any windows of Visual Studio 2010.

This means that VS 2010 shows up in all desktops, while for all other windows, VirtuaWin applies the correct behavior.

The strange thing is that this issue happens on one computer only; on the others I have it works OK.

I have checked the *Window Rules* section and nothing seems strange in there.

Is anyone else experiencing this kind of problem? Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are running Visual Studio as an administrator then Virtuawin also needs to be run as an administrator.

Comment: Excellent! This solved the issue.